# How to use Dynamic Data Masking for Json objects with multiple layers and/or arrays

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-data-masking

I was able to create a data masking policy for a json column for the top level keys with the following, but couldn't figure out to go to deeper layers in json. Anybody has done that?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MASKING POLICY json_mask_test AS
(val variant) returns variant ->
CASE
WHEN invoker_role()='ADMIN' THEN val
ELSE object_insert(
     object_insert(
     object_insert(val, 'pii_field', '***', true),
         'address','***', true),
         'lastName','***', true)
END
```

If `object_insert` is the only way to create a masking policy on a json field, looks like it's limited to top level keys.

I was using the example for [On Variant Data](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-column-ddm-use.html#additional-masking-policy-examples)

Also as a side effect this policy inserts the keys into the json fields when the keys don't exist in original field. To be able to eliminate this would be desirable.

Edit:

I have used this json for the example above
`{"regular_field": "regular data", "pii_field": "pii data"}`

I was trying to mask LastNames in a json like the following

```
'{"root":[{"employees":[
   {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
   {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
   {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}]}'
```

Comment: What is the form of your JSON in this example?

Comment: @MikeWaltonI have added the two json strings I've used for this test above.

Comment: I think the best way to accomplish this is to create a UDF that is capable of flattening, parsing, replacing, and rebuilding your VARIANT field, and then making reference to that UDF in your CASE statement in your data masking.

Comment: I have json fields with multiple layers up to 1500 keys in them, this is not going to be feasible I won't be able to create a masking policy unless Snowflake comes up with a better way

Comment: Do you flatten that data out within Snowflake or just leave it as json and allow users to query it directly?

Comment: I leave them in json and create views to flatten select columns for data consumption, I think I will create the masking policy on the views in this case.

Comment: Yeah, that was going to be my suggestion.  :-)

Comment: As a note, if you use secure views in your flatten, and don't provide access to the underlying tables, you don't need a masking policy.  You can just put the logic directly into your secure view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case above we create views to flatten json fields for consumption.

To meet the requirement, the masking policy can be applied to the view.

View definition :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_json_mask AS 
SELECT n.value:firstName::string firstName, n.value:lastName::string lastName
FROM json_test,
lateral flatten (input => v:root) r,
lateral flatten (input => r.value) e,
lateral flatten (input => e.value) n
```

I have created another masking policy for last name masking and applied to the view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MASKING POLICY lastName_mask AS
(lastName text) returns text ->
CASE
WHEN invoker_role()='ADMIN' THEN lastName
ELSE '*masked*'
END;

ALTER VIEW v_json_mask MODIFY COLUMN lastName SET MASKING POLICY lastName_mask;
```

Running `SELECT * FROM v_json_mask` with any role not specified in masking policy returns

```
FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME
John        *masked*
Anna        *masked*
Peter       *masked*
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works and was the recommended practice for masking data before Snowflake created data masking policies.  Just use RBAC to control access to the JSON table and use a Secure View.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SECURE VIEW v_json_mask AS 
SELECT n.value:firstName::string firstName, 
       CASE WHEN current_role()='ADMIN' THEN n.value:lastName::string
            ELSE '*masked*'
       END as lastName
FROM json_test,
lateral flatten (input => v:root) r,
lateral flatten (input => r.value) e,
lateral flatten (input => e.value) n
```

Comment: Yes this would work for the use case above. Thanks. But I have dozens of tables with PII columns, I would like to create a central location for data masking policies and apply them to multiple tables and views.